# How to speed video FFMPEG with Python

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I am trying to speed up video using python. But the problem is that the duration of the video output is not reduced based on the speed we provide.
If the video is 30 seconds long, the output file is accelerated. But the duration of the video remains the same.

```python
import subprocess

ffmpeg_path = r"ffmpeg\ffmpeg.exe"

speed_factor = 2
ffmpeg_args = [
    "-i", "test.mp4",
    "-loglevel", "quiet",
    "-filter:v", "setpts=0.5/{}*PTS".format(speed_factor),
    "speed.mp4"
]
subprocess.run([ffmpeg_path, *ffmpeg_args])
```

Can anyone help me with this?
`For example`: If I want speed up video by X2, for 30s duration video should reduced to 15s including audio and so on by itself without specify the timing.
Thanks

Comment: You're going to need a complex filter, because you're not changing the speed of the audio. Check out the last section [in the docs](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video).

Comment: @ZacAnger even if I changed the audio speed, the problem is still the same. The audio is played faster then the video itself

Comment: For 2x, `-filter:v setpts=PTS*1/2 -filter:a atempo=2`

Answer (score -1):

Example : I want to speed up the first 4 seconds of my video.

Cut your video
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -t 4 slow.mp4
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 00:00:04 part-2.mp4
Speed up the part
ffmpeg -i slow.mp4 -filter:v "setpts=0.5*PTS" part-1.mp4
Concatenate
ffmpeg -f concat -i <(for f in ./part-*.mp4; do echo "file '$PWD/$f'"; done) -c

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Please make sure you've read and understood the problem in the question before answering, and comment on the question if you're unsure.

Comment: It doesn't work, any other way?